# Return matching nested array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a nested "main" array and I am looking to return the results (the entire nested array) for elements matched in a second "match" array. I have been able to return the first value of the arrays desired output using (main && match) but I can find a way into the nested array.

Main:

```
[[111, [100,101,102]], [222, [200,201,202]], [333, [300,301,302]], [444, [400,401,402]], [555, [500,501,502]], [666, [600,601,602]], [777, [700,701,702]]]
```

Match:

```
[222,555,666]
```

Desired Results:

```
[[222, [200,201,202]], [555, [500,501,502]], [666, [600,601,602]]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect place to use `Array#assoc`:

```
data = [[111, [100,101,102]], [222, [200,201,202]], [333, [300,301,302]], [444, [400,401,402]], [555, [500,501,502]], [666, [600,601,602]], [777, [700,701,702]]]
match = [222,555,666]

p match.map{|i| data.assoc(i)}

#=> [[222, [200, 201, 202]], [555, [500, 501, 502]], [666, [600, 601, 602]]]
```

From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-assoc), `Array#assoc`

> Searches through an array whose elements are also arrays comparing obj
>   with the first element of each contained array using obj.==.
>
> Returns the first contained array that matches (that is, the first
>   associated array), or nil if no match is found.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `select` to match on the first element in each of the sub-arrays:

```
data = [[111, [100,101,102]], [222, [200,201,202]], [333, [300,301,302]], [444, [400,401,402]], [555, [500,501,502]], [666, [600,601,602]], [777, [700,701,702]]]

match = [222, 555, 666]

results = data.select{|x| match.include?(x[0])}

p results

#=> [[222, [200, 201, 202]], [555, [500, 501, 502]], [666, [600, 601, 602]]]
```